# Confiforms Textarea not showing placeholder text

Tags: confluence, confluence-macros

I've got a weird issue.  I was doing some minor modifications on a form built with confiforms.  I've added placeholder text to several of the fields.  These fields are type textarea.  When I save and view the page there is no placeholder text in those fields.  There is, however, a space in the field.  If I delete the space the placeholder's display.  I have no clue why confluence would be putting a space in those fields.  Placeholders work on text fields, but not textarea fields.  I can't find anything in the documentation or online suggesting this is a problem, I am stumped.  I am the space admin, but not a confluence admin.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried removing the space between the opening and closing tag of the textarea, if there are any blank spaces they come as an input to your textarea.
if this doesnt work try aria-placeholder
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-placeholder

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, I do not have control over the type of textarea.  I'm using Confiforms to build a form in Confluence.  All the field types are predefined by the macro and the type can't be modified.   

If I use the preview functionality it works.  but the actual form once save seems to add a space causing the placeholder not to be seen.  I have no idea why?  and it doesn't happen at all the company's locations.  It's really strange.

Comment: Can you share part of that line of code